# Sample Application - Amazon S3 / Indy / Delphi

Tags: delphi, amazon-s3, indy

I am looking for an example application to store objects to Amazon S3 using INDY components.

Any help much appreciated.

Phillip

Answer (score 4):

Here's a demo with Synapse, it should be easy to use Indy instead:
http://www.itwriting.com/s3example_21dec06.zip